# How do I transfer files, along with history, from one Git project to another?

Tags: git, version-control

What are the steps to transfer selected files, along with their history, from one project to another in Git? For example, I have

```
Project A
    File A.1
    File A.2
    File a.3
    File a.4

Project B
    File B.1
    File B.2
```

which are unrelated (through Git) and I want to end up with

```
Project B
    File B.1
    File B.2
    File A.1
    File A.2
```

along with full histories for A.1 and A.2, but none for a.3 or a.4, (assume for simplicity I don't care whether A.1 and A.2 also leave histories in Project B). What what are the steps involved? I can gather from reading here and elsewhere that this is possible, but I'm having trouble pasting the bits and pieces into a step by step workflow.

Comment: Is `Project B` a fork, branch, or clone of `Project A`?

Comment: @SamSullivan: Good question. Project B is distinct from Project A: no relationship through Git. Edited.

Comment: I'd try creating a new repo of `Project B`, and then using some ideas from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) to merge `Project A`'s history into `Project B`..

Comment: That will give me all of A in B though, right?

Comment: Oh yea..there is no great way to do this.  You could *potentially* checkout a new branch on `Project B`, merge in `Project A`, remove unwanted files (everything but `File A` and `File B`), then merge this temporary branch into your main `Project B` branch.

Comment: @SamSullivan: That sounds like part of the solution. But the question is: what's the procedure, and how do I eliminate history for the files I don't want to move over?

Comment: I just posted an answer that does step-by-step and includes eliminating history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dislamer: it is probably good to push both repositories to a remote host like GitHub or BitBucket before attempting. I just tried locally and all went well, but no guarantees.*

This is a multi-step process, and it may not be a perfect solution.  Starting with 2 local repositories, `Project A` and `Project B`.  They may have some overlapping files and both may have some history.  The end goal is to merge `Project A` into `Project B`, keep the history, but completely remove select files from the final repo.

Start by merging `Project A` into `Project B`.  To do this, we will have add `Project A` as a remote branch to `Project B`.

```
git remote add old /path/to/project_a   # old is the remote name
git fetch old <branch>                  # fetch history from Project A (can specify single branch after)
git merge old/<branch>                  # merge the Project A branch into your working tree (most likely master)
```

Now you will have a merged `Project A` and `Project B` in `Project B`'s working tree.  You may have merge conflicts to resolve (if so, commit after this).

Next step is to remove our unwanted files (or directories) from this combined repository.  `git filter-branch` will be used to do this historically. **Note: this will rewrite history, so if someone is working off of `Project B` there will be major conflicts and is not recommended** (instead, just remove the files normally and make an extra commit..this will keep history sane).

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/unwanted/dirs' HEAD
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f unwanted_file' HEAD
```

This translates to run this command in every commit of this tree (branch) up until the `HEAD` (working copy).  You can also specify a range by replacing it `HEAD` with `a1b2c3...HEAD`.  The `-r` in the first command is needed to recursively remove files from an unwanted directory.  The `-f` is needed in both commands to ignore non-existent files (some commits may not have the file you want to remove, since the commits come from 2 repositories).

Finally you can cleanup by removing the link between `Project B` and the old `Project A`.

```
git remote rm old    # or whatever you named this branch
```

Comment: FWIW: For `filter-branch` I had to make sure that I'd simplified the structure of my project considerably (removing any remotes and paring down to a single branch). And I ended up using different flags (neither those above nor the ones I found in other answers worked smoothly). But that's all probably down to some peculiarities of my project structure. I also reversed the steps, prunig (a copy of) A before merging into B.

Comment: Good notes @raxacoricofallapatorius.  I haven't ever used `filter-branch` in a real scenario, so not sure what up with it..but I'm glad you were able to get everything sorted.